# Is it possible to display output of /data from a command block?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm playing 1.14 and wanted to test some villager mechanics in a creative world. To help debugging I thought it'd be a good idea to constantly print the home/workplace information of the closest  villager, which is found in the `Brain` tag of the NBT data. So I wrote the following command:

```
/data get entity @e[type=minecraft:villager,limit=1,sort=nearest] Brain
```

And it works great:

[image: command output]

So now I thought I could just put this in a command block and trigger it every second to have easy debugging. So I put this in a command block:

```
/execute as orlp at orlp run data get entity @e[type=minecraft:villager,limit=1,sort=nearest] Brain
```

However I don't get any output on triggering the command block. Even `/gamerule commandBlockOutput true` doesn't make it output anything.

How do I output the result of a `data` command ran in a command block to chat (or otherwise)?

Comment: I'm afraid the only way to do this through the command block is by looking into command block, which isn't any better than executing the command by yourself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes! 1.14 added NBT as a JSON component. So you can now print NBT like this:

```
/tellraw @s {"nbt":"Brain","entity":"@e[type=villager]"}
```

This even works for multiple entities (unlike `/data get`), which puts "`,`" between the NBT outputs (which usually leads to the second and further tags appearing in a new line, because Minecraft only wraps lines on spaces, which aren't normally in NBT).

You can also output all NBT of an entity like this:

```
/tellraw @s {"nbt":"","entity":"@e[type=villager]"}
```

It also works for blocks:

```
/tellraw @s {"nbt":"","block":"12 -34 56"}
```

And you can combine "`block`" and "`entity`", then "`entity`" just gets ignored.

And as a special treat, you can even interpret that NBT as a JSON component, for example if you give a villager a formatted name like this:

```
/summon minecraft:villager ~ ~ ~ {CustomName:"{\"text\":\"Horst\",\"bold\":true}"}
```

…, then you can either output that JSON as text:

```
/tellraw @s {"nbt":"CustomName","entity":"@e[type=villager]"}
```

Output: `{"bold":true,"text":"Horst"}`

… or you can output it how it appears on top of its head:

```
/tellraw @s {"nbt":"CustomName","entity":"@e[type=villager]","interpret":true}
```

Output: **`Horst`**

And finally you can get really crazy and recursive:

```
/give @s written_book{author:"",title:"",pages:["{\"nbt\":\"CustomName\",\"entity\":\"@e[type=villager]\",\"interpret\":true}"]}
/tellraw @s {"nbt":"Inventory[0].tag.pages[0]","entity":"@s"}
```

Output: `{"nbt":"CustomName","entity":"@e[type=villager]","interpret":true}`

And interpreted:

```
/tellraw @s {"nbt":"Inventory[0].tag.pages[0]","entity":"@s","interpret":true}
```

Output: **`Horst`**

Note that this changes when you open the book, because then the JSON gets interpreted and the book page changes from `{"nbt":"CustomName","entity":"@e[type=villager]","interpret":true}` to **`Horst`**.

Comment: Can I use `limit=1,sort=nearest` within the `tellraw` if I prefix the `tellraw` with `/execute as orlp at orlp run`?

Comment: Sure. If "orlp" is you, you don't even need to do that.

Comment: orlp is indeed me. If I didn't do that how would the command block know what to center the `nearest` sort on then?

Comment: @orlp The command executor.